# MySQL Create Trigger (incl Variables) Syntax

Tags: mysql, triggers

Having a little trouble with the `END` Trigger syntax, getting:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 30

...any idea what it is failing on?

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_tblOptymaster_AFTER_UPDATE //

CREATE TRIGGER trg_tblOptymaster_AFTER_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE ON tblOptyMaster 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 DECLARE DateFrom DATE;
 DECLARE DateTo DATE;

 SET @DateFrom=DATE_ADD(OLD.DueDate, INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
 SET @DateTo=DATE_ADD(NEW.DueDate, INTERVAL 6 MONTH);

 INSERT INTO tblOptyDueDateMovement 
    (
    OpportunityCRMID, 
    SnapshotDate, 
    DueDateFrom, 
    DueDateTo,
    DueDateSlippage_Days,
    DueDateSlippage_Months,
    DueDateSlippage_FYs
    ) 
    VALUES 
    (
    NEW.OpportunityCRMID, 
    NEW.SnapshotDate,
    OLD.DueDate,
    NEW.DueDate,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,DueDateFrom, DueDateTo),
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,DueDateFrom, DueDateTo),
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,@DateFrom, @DateTo)
    )

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The error message does not match your code.

Comment: Sorry, I'd tried again before submitting and changed it slightly. I've corrected some, still got issues with the END...

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got it right, I find the delimiters and syntax can be a little confusing as I don't use MySQL all the time:

I'd missed a `;` after the VALUES()

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_tblOptymaster_AFTER_UPDATE //

CREATE TRIGGER trg_tblOptymaster_AFTER_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE ON tblOptyMaster 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 DECLARE DateFrom DATE;
 DECLARE DateTo DATE;

 SET @DateFrom=DATE_ADD(OLD.DueDate, INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
 SET @DateTo=DATE_ADD(NEW.DueDate, INTERVAL 6 MONTH);

 INSERT INTO tblOptyDueDateMovement 
    (
    OpportunityCRMID, 
    SnapshotDate, 
    DueDateFrom, 
    DueDateTo,
    DueDateSlippage_Days,
    DueDateSlippage_Months,
    DueDateSlippage_FYs
    ) 
    VALUES 
    (
    NEW.OpportunityCRMID, 
    NEW.SnapshotDate,
    OLD.DueDate,
    NEW.DueDate,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,DueDateFrom, DueDateTo),
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,DueDateFrom, DueDateTo),
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,@DueDateFrom, @DueDateTo)
    );

END//
DELIMITER ;
```